# How can I predict the next image from a series of images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am planing to predict the next image from an image sequence. I have searched on the internet (Google/YouTube) for tutorials and for similar work. but I couldn't find any.
I want to know whether it is possible to find the pattern and predict the next image and can I find some tutorials for that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have found some papers. They explain some theories. but the problem is I couldn't understand where to start.

Comment: well if you cannot understand where to start you obviously don't have enough knowledge. I'm afraid you'll have to learn :)

Comment: That's why I ask that whether there is any tutorial that I can follow and learn

Comment: how well do you know machine learning?

Comment: I know only basics of machine learning. I have followed some tutorials about classification etc using tensorflow. I don't know where to start..

Comment: if websearch doesn't yield any tutorials, it is very unlikely that there are any useful ones. so you'll have to stick with the papers. those papers are usually not written for beginners and there are no tutorials because the target readers do not need tutorials. while you will find plenty of first aid trainings for everyone you won't find a beginners training for brain surgery, if you know what I mean. read those papers.  thoroughly research everything you don't understand until you do.  learn to solve the atomic problems instead of the whole problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try to understand papers and go thorough them

Comment: @ViduraJayalath If you want to avoid unconstructive comments, you can add a section "what I tried". In this case, you should add a couple of papers and a few of the parts you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CNN:

- The input is then not 3 * w * h but (3*number of images) * w * h - so you can just concatenate the stuff in depth
- The output is just an image instead of a class. So no flattening in between... or a reshape has to be added.

Have a look at 
[Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06211) and Image-to-Image translation.

If you haven't seen it already: [Keras](https://keras.io) is pretty handy.

You might also be interested in the concept of [Optical Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll follow this path