# How do I test CNN model for less classes than training set in python

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have tropical storms images and trying build up a model to categorize the storm category. Here I am trying to predict the last storm stage using previous storm images but Last storm accounts only 5 categories training set has 7 categories( basically I split dataset like last storm for testing and first storms as training).Finally I have to ask, are there any methods to predict less classes than training classes.

Comment: I'm a little confused: what are the "extra" classes? It's true that you can simply take the highest value from among the classes in which you are interested as @hwei-geok-ng suggests, but I don't understand why your training and inferencing data have different shapes.

Comment: These are storm category images. I have 14 storms .I want to make a model using 13 storms and predict the last one. So my test one is the last one. First 13 storms has 7 categories(each storm has several images  for several categories and for example sometimes storm start with category 1 and goes to category 3 so that storm has no data about rest of categories). In this case last storm has only 5 categories.

Comment: I now understand that you are trying to predict the next image in sequence instead of treating it as a pure classification problem. Maybe this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49731169/14328644) would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it does not matter if your test set contains fewer categories than the training categories as long as the 5 categories that you care about can still be predicted by the model. When the model produces a prediction for a given test sample, you can sort the predicted classes and take only the predicted class with the highest accuracy (or top 3 accuracies, for example) and ignore the rest.

Otherwise, I would suggest training your model only with the number of classes you care about (5) with only the training set of these classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got low testing accuracy when I was doing with all 7 categories. In this case any storm cannot represents the all categories. When we use any of them as a testing set ,its accuracy is falling down.